# Trouble weight painting character

Tags: weight-painting

I tried my best to rig my first character, but every time I try to weight paint something seems to go wrong. The automatic weights are ok but need some editing. However every time I try  to do  that I seem to make it worse instead of better.

What are perhaps some good tutorials to learn this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If I select the shoulder bone (the one that affects the mesh and that is on the first armature layer, not the one on the third armature layer), you can see that it influences the neck area (and also the head) when it should not.

Other bones affect the head as well. You need to correct this, for example with the weight paint brush in *Subtract* mode.

Also maybe simplify your mesh, it will make things easier, unless you have some good reason not to use a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. And why not simplify the armature as well?

[image]

Comment: Thank you moonboots, you are very very helpful. I understand what you are saying.I tried to do what you suggested and weight paint with the subsurface modifier not permanently applied yet however that gives me too little vertex point to work with to weight paint for the bones in my armature. I prefer to keep this armature.

Comment: I left the weights in the neck because that is what the automatic weights gave me, however when I try to correct them (Like you said) I get those glitches again. I think I need to smooth the weight painting out better, but whenever I spend hours trying to do that, I keep having these glitches. Perhaps I am overlooking something simple. Do know if there is a tutorial I should watch? Or do you perhaps know of a method yourself.
Thank you once again for your time I really appreciate it.

Comment: you must make a mistake in the settings. First in the Tool bar on the left select the Draw brush, then in the N panel on the right > Tool > Brush Settings, choose Blend > Subtract, Weight > 1, Stregth > 1, to be able to paint through, in Advanced disable Front Face Only, in Falloff choose Projected and disable Front-Face Falloff. It should work fine. But you also need to correct the other bones: bones of the arm, of the torso, of the belly, they also influence the head!

Comment: Thank you for your responses it brought me a few steps closer :)